# Google Docs Time report - How to add hours?

Tags: google-sheets

I use a Google Docs spreadsheet to keep track of the time I spend on projects.  It's formatted in 3 columns: the time I started, the time I finished, and the total hours spent for that session (represented as a decimal).

```
+---+---------+----------+---------------+
|   |    A    |    B     |       C       |
+---+---------+----------+---------------+
| 1 | Started | Finished | Hours/Session |
| 2 | 9:30    | 11:00    | 1.5           |
| 3 | 9:45    | 12:00    | 2.25          |
+---+---------+----------+---------------+
```

Right now I'm using my fingers (which is ridiculously un-poweruser like) to add up the total number of hours from start to finish.  Is there a way to do this automatically?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It may be a little late, but here is how I do it:

```
=HOUR(B2-A2)+(MINUTE(B2-A2)/60)
```

Basically, being **B2** the **end time** and **A2** the **start time**, you subtract B2-A2 and get the hour from the subtraction. Then you do the same and get the amount of minutes. After you have both, you sum the **amount of hours** with the **amount of minutes divided by 60** (to get it in hours).

Don't forget to use the 24-hour format (i.e. 10:00 or 22:00).

Answer (score 7):

Google Sheets now have a duration formatting option. Select: Format -> Number -> Duration.

Answer (score 3):

Now-a-days one can use the `ARRAYFORMULA` as well, to save some time:

`=ARRAYFORMULA((HOUR(B2:B-A2:A)+(MINUTE(B2:B-A2:A)/60)))`

See example file: [Hours](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdHctM0lKWVdmbjR4Tk90SXEwR0o0bkE)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a formula:

1. Type this in the first cell of `hours/seesion`: `=(B2-A2)*24` *(assuming A2 is the starting time and B2 the end time)*
2. Click in the right corner of that cell and drag it down the whole column.
3. Select the whole column (click on the column letter)
4. click on `123` in the toolbar
5. click on `Normal`

Comment: Everything worked except the formula, which produces negative numbers

Answer (score 2):

given `A: start time` and `B: end time` i use this:

```
=(IF(A2 < B2; 0; 1)+B2 - A2) * 24
```

the `if` part is needed to calculate day-switch correctly, eg. you start at 10:00 and work till 02:00 (the other day), you would end up with with `-8` hours instead of `14`, bad for business i'd guess.

Comment: This formula didn't produce negative numbers, but the resulting numbers were still wrong

Comment: I liked this one best, but I used `=(IF(A2 <= B2; 0; 1)+B2 - A2) * 24` (note the `<=` at the beginning) so that start and end times that matched (and empty cells) would be zero instead of 24.

Answer (score 1):

**Be aware** that your **'time cells'** are **formatted the right way!**

I just learned that google docs with Danish settings will need time formatted like this:

```
+---+---------+----------+
| 1 | Started | Finished |
| 2 | 9.30    | 11.00    |
| 3 | 9.45    | 12.00    |
+---+---------+----------+
```

**cinaglia**'s working formula above only works when google docs spreadsheet recognizes the cells as (time) numbers.
I guess this is probably logic for beginners but I looked around a WHOLE LOT before I changed the 'colons' to 'periods' - and got the formula working (thanks **cinaglia**).

Answer (score -2):

wow people... =text(end time cell- start time cell, "h:mm")
BUT now am finding this string bc google sheets can not add up the clean hours column.  Help.  I MISS EXCEL SO MUCH!!!